# Using Java Highlighter to highlight multiple matches

Tags: java, swing, highlight

I'm trying to get my highlighter to highlight all the matches to a regex. My regex is working correctly and is providing the proper start and end to the highlighter. The highligher, however,  continues to highlight subsequent text. See attached picture.

[image]

```
    class CommandAreaDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    Pattern variables
            = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("(?<variable>\\$\\w*\\$)");

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // System.out.println(commandArea.getText());
        validate(commandArea.getText());

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // System.out.println(commandArea.getText());
        validate(commandArea.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        //  System.out.println(commandArea.getText());
        validate(commandArea.getText());
    }

    private void validate(String s) {
        Matcher matcher = variables.matcher(s);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new HighlighterRunnable(matcher));

    }

    class HighlighterRunnable implements Runnable {

        Matcher matcher;

        public HighlighterRunnable(Matcher m) {
            this.matcher = m;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // System.out.println("Running!");
            while (matcher.find()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount() + 1; i++) {

                    try {
                        // commandArea.append("\nGroup #" + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
                        // commandArea.append(" , " + matcher.end(i));
                        int start = matcher.start(i);
                        int end = matcher.end(i);
                        commandArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, end, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);

                        //  if (matchCount == 1) inputArea.setCaretPosition(start);
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CommandPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter` is all the same color. You have to extend that and override `paint(Graphics g)` to change colors

Comment: Can not reproduce. Using your regex and your loop for highlighting, highlighting works just fine, even when altering/inserting text afterwards. However, the highlight stays around the `$...$` even when I add spaces in between. Did you do something like this? Have you tried calling `removeAllHighlights()` before adding new highlights?

Comment: Mine highlights everthing after the first match. For example, hello "$world$ hello " highlights everthing after $world$

Comment: you should be remove all DefaultHighlighters from arrays of DefaultHighlighters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why i had to do this, but creating a new DefaultHighlighter in the "run()" fixed the issue. Not sure how the others were seeing different results with my code. Here is the fix:

```
            @Override
        public void run() {
            // System.out.println("Running!");
            commandArea.setHighlighter(new DefaultHighlighter());
            while (matcher.find()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
                    try {
                        int start = matcher.start(i);
                        int end = matcher.end(i);
                        System.out.println("start=" + start + " end=" + end);
                        commandArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(start, end, new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.CYAN));
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CommandPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried whether `commandArea.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights()` has the same effect?

Comment: Where and why? From what I know, the start and end should tell the highlighter where to start and end. I'm still not sure why creating a new HighLigher worked.

Comment: See my comment under your question. My theory is that some "old" highlights remain and thus everything is highlighted. Doing `removeAllHighlights()` instead of `setHighlighter(new DefaultHighlighter())` might have a similar effect then, but IMHO feels a lot cleaner.